# How to generically serialize and de-serialize objects from dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, generic-programming

While writing a little service I found that I'd like to build Python objects from dictionaries and then "serialize" them back into dictionaries.

Currently my problem is the result of doing so using a mix of `itemgetter` and `vars`. Not giving me the expected result. More concretely:

```
from operator import itemgetter

class Object(object):
    def __init__(self, foo: str, bar: int):
        self.foo, self.bar = foo, bar

    @staticmethod
    def from_dict(dictionary):
        attributes = ["foo", "bar"]
        return Object(*itemgetter(*attributes)(dictionary))
```

So we have this static method called `from_dict` that should take a dictionary and return a `Object` object.

This is the behavior I would like:

```
>> d = {"foo": "frobulate", "bar": 42}
>> obj = Object.from_dict(d)
>> vars(obj)
{"foo": "frobulate", "bar": 42}
```

However, what I get instead is:

```
>> d = {"foo": "frobulate", "bar": 42}
>> obj = Object.from_dict(d)
>> vars(obj)
{"foo": ("frobulate",), "bar": (42,)}
```

Where the attributes are set as single element tuples.

Is there a clean python way of getting this give me the behavior I expect?

I'm trying to avoid duplication like:

```
class Object(object):
    ...
    @staticmethod
    def from_dict(dictionary):
        return Object(foo=dictionary["foo"],bar=dictionary["bar"])
```

Eventually I'd like to have a generic method that takes a class `cls` and can parse any object from a dictionary:

```
def parse_object_from_dict(cls, attributes, dictionary):
    return cls(*itemgetter(*attributes)(dictionary))
```

That could be used like:

```
>> foo = parse_object_from_dict(Foo, ["a", "b"], {"a": 42, "b": 42})
>> obj = parse_object_from_dict(Object, ["foo", "bar"], {"foo": 42, "bar": 42}
```

And have the attributes set as expected (not as single element tuples!).

Is this possible? Or even a good idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For what you are describing, you should be using a class method. You are requiring that the input dictionary have the same keys as the arguments in the `__init__` function, but beyond that you are just pushing the key-value pairs to the object.

```
class Object:
    def __init__(self, foo, bar):
        self.foo = foo
        self.bar = bar

    @classmethod
    def from_dict(cls, d):
        ob = cls(**d)
        for k,v in d.items():
            setattr(ob, str(k), v)    
        return ob
```

Comment: Thanks! A simple solution. I should certainly be using a `@classmethod`. Your answer inspired me to read the docs on that decorator and it totally makes sense since it's an alternative initializer.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is with `setattr`

```
class Object(object):
    def __init__(self, foo=None, bar=None):
        self.foo = foo
        self.bar = bar

    @staticmethod
    def from_dict(dic):
        obj = Object()
        [setattr(obj, attr, dic[attr]) for attr in ["foo", "bar"]]
        return obj
```

Another way is using `**` but can be a sloppy way to do things and can throw errors if your dictionary contains extra keys.

```
class Object(object):
    def __init__(self, foo, bar):
        self.foo = foo
        self.bar = bar

    @staticmethod
    def from_dict(dic):
        return Object(**dic)

data = {'foo': 'a', 'bar': 2}
o = Object.from_dict(data)

data = {'foo': 'a', 'bar': 2, 'baz': 3}
o = Object.from_dict(data) # this will throw an error due to the 'baz' key
```

One final way to do it, which is probably the cleanest way, is to try using Marshmallow, which will handle serialization and deserialization for you.

https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/3.0/api_reference.html